# Ejabberd + iOS XMPPFramework.. not connecting to server

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am attempting to connect to an ejabberd server hosted here:

198.199.106.154:5280

The issue is that this block of code is not calling iOS XMPP Framework's delegate: 
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender

I am confident that my server has made a connection because the following log appears on the server after the code has executed:
[image: serverlog]

```
- (void)setupStream {

xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
xmppStream.hostName = @"198.199.106.154";
xmppStream.hostPort = 5280;
NSString * jabberID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"admin@%@", @"localhost"];
[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];

NSError *error2 = nil;
[xmppStream connectWithTimeout:10.0f error:&error2];
NSLog(@"here is the connect error %@", [error2 localizedDescription]); //NO ERROR IS CALLED!


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self authWithServer];
     NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(authWithServer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
//I GET THE FOLLOWING MESSAGE:: "Please wait until the stream is connected"
});


[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

}
```

I am absolutely lost folks! Any guidance would be immensely helpful

Comment: did u resolve this issue @user330739

Answer (score 3):

XMPPFramework uses standard XMPP TCP connection (which handled by ejabberd_c2s module usually on 5222 port), but you are trying connect to http-bind module, which is not implemented in XMPPFramework.